# Using this.property returns undefined inside a method on prototype

Tags: javascript, node.js

In the following snippet I made an event emitter which executes all the event when called. I used a function constructor and added `on` and `emit` methods on it.
The even `transfer` updates the objects property `amount`.
But when I access `this.amount` inside `on` it returns undefined.
***emitter.js***

```
function Account(n) {
    this.balance=n;
    this.events = {}
}
Account.prototype.on =  function(type, listener){
    this.events[type] = this.events[type] || [];
    this.events[type].push(listener);
}

Account.prototype.emmit =  function(type){
    if(this.events[type]) {
        this.events[type].forEach(listener => {

            listener();
        });
    }
    console.log("Amount transfered. Total Balance is " + this.balance);
}
module.exports = Account;
```

***app.js***

```
const Account = require('./emitter');

const myAccount = new Account(5);
myAccount.on('transfer', function(amount = 10){
    this.balance += amount;
    console.log(amount + ' Rs. has been transferrered! Balance is ' + this.balance);
});

myAccount.on('transfer', function(amount = 30){
    this.balance += amount;
    console.log(amount + 'Rs. has been transferrered! Balance is ' + this.balance);
});

myAccount.on('transfer', function(amount = 40){
    this.balance += amount;
    console.log(amount + 'Rs. has been transferrered! Balance is ' + this.balance);
});
myAccount.emmit('transfer');
```

This is what I have already tried.
I think that this.events is already an object so `this` inside it will refer to the current object not the parent object.
So tried accessing the property `myAccount.amount`. Still it returns `undefined`
I also tried storing reference of `this` in a variable `that` and instead of accessing property in `this.amount`, i  tried `that.amount` still undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are not passing 'this' to your listener callback function.

Change `listener()` invocation to this:

```
listener.call(this);
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit? why this doesn't work `listener(this)` and `listener.call(this) ` works

Comment: this in JavaScript is an *environment variable*, it cannot be passed or set by parameters. In order to call a function and pass `this` into it you shall use either `.call(this,...)`, `.apply(this,...)` or `.bind(this,...)` 
Check this:
https://medium.com/@owenyangg/javascript-call-apply-and-bind-explained-to-a-total-noob-63f146684564

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari You can find a good but general explanation in: "[How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)" – The value of `this` in a given function depends on how that function was invoked. In this case, calling `listener()` as a plain function will use a global default as the value of `this`, while adding `.call(this)` allows you to provide a value of your choosing.